# Remove Last Character in R inplace

Tags: r, dataframe

I came from a Python background and I am working in R with this data `df`.

```
    name   age
1  Anon1   52a
2  Anon2   62
3  Anon3   44a
4  Anon4   30
5  Anon5   110a
```

**Using R language**, how can I remove the `a` in the last part of the age column and do data modification in place??

`(just like Python using inplace=True)`

Can I attain it using

```
df$Age[which(df$Age == `a pattern`)] <- ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for `parse_number` from `readr` package (it is in `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df %>% 
  mutate(age = parse_number(age))
```

```
   name age
1 Anon1  52
2 Anon2  62
3 Anon3  44
4 Anon4  30
5 Anon5 110
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("Anon1", "Anon2", "Anon3", "Anon4", "Anon5"
), age = c("52a", "62", "44a", "30", "110a")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sub` here:

```r
df$age <- sub("a$", "", df$age, fixed=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#A tidy solution
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(name=c("anon1","anon2"),age=c("52","37a"))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(age = str_extract(age,"^\\d+"))

df
   name age
1 anon1  52
2 anon2  37
```

Comment: What does the "^\\d+" mean??

Comment: capture 1 or more digits at start of string

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches. No packages are used.

**1)** We remove all non-digit characters where in a regular expression \D means non-digit.  If we knew that only `a` could appear as a non-digit we could , instead, use `"a"` as the first argument to `gsub` and if we knew it only appears once we could use `sub` instead of `gsub`.

Also it is easier to debug code if you don't overwrite variables since then you always know that a particular variable is in its original state. Instead assign the result to a new variable.

```
transform(DF, age = as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", age)))
```

This could also be written using pipes:

```
transform(DF, age = age |> gsub(pattern = "\\D", replacement = "") |> as.numeric())
```

**2)** We can use `scan` specifying that `a` is a comment character.

```
transform(DF, age = scan(text = age, comment.char = "a", quiet = TRUE))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
    name   age
1  Anon1   52a
2  Anon2   62
3  Anon3   44a
4  Anon4   30
5  Anon5   110a"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `inplace` modifier in python refers to making a change without creating a copy. The `data.table` package in R allows for this (called replace by reference).

```
df <- read.table(text="
   name   age
1  Anon1   52a
2  Anon2   62
3  Anon3   44a
4  Anon4   30
5  Anon5   110a")

library(data.table)
library(stringi)
setDT(df)[, age:=stri_extract(age, regex='^\\d+')]
df
```

The first clause (`setDT(df)`) converts `df` to a `data.table` by reference (e.g., without making a copy), and the second clause (`[, age:=...]`) replaces the values in column `age` with `...` also by reference.